# Indication when RecyclerView last item is visible

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have an activity which contain horizontal RecyclerView which display icons of movies retrieved from server

When the user scroll the recycler view to its end - making the last item of the recycler view visible i want to show "More" button to allow the loading of additional icons

How can i get indication when the user scroll to the end of the recycler view?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
recyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
        @Override
        public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
            super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);
            if (((LinearLayoutManager) recyclerView.getLayoutManager()).findLastVisibleItemPosition() == LAST_POSITION) {
                // code here
            }
        }
    });
```